# Google vr v1.0 - How i make character follow the head rotation in unity ?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, google-vr

i started to make a VR  Fps game but i'm not able to get the rotation right 
i used this method to track the rotation of the head. 
the character is a parent and child is camera to track the position.
I used this code but it keep rotate all time.

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, theCamera.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

so i removed the camera and put it separated from character and used this script to set position same as character

```
transform.localPosition = (ch.transform.position+ pos_head);
```

where ch is character and pos_head the distance of head from center

but when i try to rotate 180 degree i saw the back of character head

so what is the appropriate way to implement the camera?

Comment: character has child of the camera?

Comment: Yes but I removed it to stop the infinite loop of rotates

Comment: The problem now how to make the camera as a fps camera and keep same position like a head